# Cxf reuse already generated jaxb classes

Tags: java, jaxb, cxf

I do have a wsdl file which already uses an existing xsd from our project(so the generated Jaxb classes are also in this project).

I've looked up how to reuse jaxb classes and found the following: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/12/reusing-generated-jaxb-classes.html

So I've done the following:

1. xjc -d out -episode  My.xsd -p
2. wsdl2java -p  -client-xjc -b  -fe jaxws21 My.wsdl

Now I wanted to test this service with the JaxWsProxyFactoryBean:

```
    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
    factory.setServiceClass(servicClass);
    factory.setAddress(url);
    factory.setUsername(user);
    factory.setPassword(password);
    Object messageHandler = factory.create();
    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(messageHandler);
```

When creating the client I get this exception which I don't understand:

```
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't parse argument number ''{0}''
at java.text.MessageFormat.makeFormat(MessageFormat.java:1339)[:1.6.0_25]
at java.text.MessageFormat.applyPattern(MessageFormat.java:458)[:1.6.0_25]
at java.text.MessageFormat.<init>(MessageFormat.java:350)[:1.6.0_25]
at java.text.MessageFormat.format(MessageFormat.java:811)[:1.6.0_25]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.Messages.format(Messages.java:133)[jaxb-impl-2.2.5-2.jar:2.2.5-2]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeInfoSetImpl.add(TypeInfoSetImpl.java:306)[jaxb-impl-2.2.5-2.jar:2.2.5-2]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RegistryInfoImpl.<init>(RegistryInfoImpl.java:121)[jaxb-impl-2.2.5-2.jar:2.2.5-2]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.addRegistry(ModelBuilder.java:362)[jaxb-impl-2.2.5-2.jar:2.2.5-2]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:332)[jaxb-impl-2.2.5-2.jar:2.2.5-2]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:460)[jaxb-impl-2.2.5-2.jar:2.2.5-2]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:298)[jaxb-impl-2.2.5-2.jar:2.2.5-2]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:141)[jaxb-impl-2.2.5-2.jar:2.2.5-2]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1163)[jaxb-impl-2.2.5-2.jar:2.2.5-2]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:145)[jaxb-impl-2.2.5-2.jar:2.2.5-2]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.6.0_25]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)[:1.6.0_25]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)[:1.6.0_25]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)[:1.6.0_25]
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:202)[:1.6.0_25]
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:363)[:1.6.0_25]
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)[:1.6.0_25]
at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:267)[cxf-api-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:265)[cxf-api-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.6.0_25]
at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.createContext(JAXBContextCache.java:265)[cxf-api-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.getCachedContextAndSchemas(JAXBContextCache.java:172)[cxf-api-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.createJAXBContextAndSchemas(JAXBDataBinding.java:464)[cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:330)[cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)[cxf-rt-core-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:478)[cxf-rt-core-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:690)[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:540)[cxf-rt-core-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:252)[cxf-rt-core-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:205)[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:102)[cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:90)[cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:156)[cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:156)[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
```

I noticed that the JaxbContext is created with all classes of the new stub and the existing stub which I don't know if this really correct.
I've also tried to specify a different JaxbDataBinding where I don't use all classes, but then i get different errors.

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: I've found why I get this exception: Jaxb wanted to tell me the error CONFLICTING_XML_ELEMENT_MAPPING = \
    The element name '{'{0}'}'{1} has more than one mapping. But it couldn't parse this String from the messages.properties file. I'm looking forward why ...

Comment: The exception only occures when using german language.

Comment: Thr real exception is now an IllegalAnnotation exception because of duplicate methods in the new and the old ObjectFactory. The only way to get this working was to remove the methods from the new ObjectFactory. Is there a better way to get this working?